# What should I do when I first get an LCD to deal with any quality issues?

Tags: lcd, stuck-pixel

I just ordered a new Dell 2209WA.  Reviews seem to indicate it doesn't have any known quality control problems, but I read in general about LCD's and how people check for dead pixels, even unsticking them, and use burn-in programs.

So any recommendations or links on what I should do when I first receive the LCD?

Also, could someone please weight in on the idea of burn-in for LCDs?

Comment: I made it CW since there isn't going to be a "best" answer out of this. However that doesn't mean it's a bad question

Comment: @Ivo - CW is not a punishment, it has a purpose. No reason that would be linked to "bad questions"

Comment: You know it, I know it. Now for the rest of the users ;-)

Comment: @Ivo - exactly, no reason for you to specify such thing for the rest of users, this is what I mean. Because saying so is saying a bit "but other times a CW is for bad questions". Which is of course wrong ;)

Answer (score 6):

My notes on checking LCD pixels:

> Explain to the sales droid that LCD
>   displays can have dead (or permanently
>   alive) pixels. It probably won't know
>   that knackered pixels are expected,
>   but the vast majority of displays are
>   perfect, so there's no harm in making
>   sure you get a perfect one. Unpack the
>   display and plug it into a PC in the
>   store. Now you need to check both a
>   completely white screen and a
>   completely black screen - because
>   knackered pixels can be knackered
>   either always on or always off. An LCD
>   'turns on' its pixel so it becomes
>   opaque - that is, black. A pixel is
>   'turned off' (goes clear) and lets the
>   white backlight through it to display
>   white. This is why LCD's are not as
>   good at displaying black as CRT's. The
>   backlight is always on, and the pixels
>   can have varying degrees of opaqueness
>   when turned on. This makes black more
>   of an uneven very dark gray (well,
>   uneven on my LCD anyway..newer ones
>   might be better at it)
>
> To check always off, fire up Internet
>   Explorer, go to "about:blank" and
>   press F11 (full screen). This will
>   give you a page full of white. Scan
>   the page closely looking for "always
>   off" dead pixels.
>
> Then, to test for always on pixels,
>   right click on the desktop and go to
>   screen saver. Select "Blank" and then
>   "Preview". Again, scan the blank
>   screen and this time look for "always
>   on" pixels - although these are much
>   easier to spot!
>
> Then go to
>   javscript:void(document.bgColor='red'),
>   javscript:void(document.bgColor='green'),
>   and
>   javscript:void(document.bgColor='blue')
>   with Full Screen (F11) after each
>   color.

I knocked these notes together from some slashdot posts a few years ago.

Comment: Interesting way to do that using what you have on the computer already.

Comment: This is great info, but I'm talking about testing/burnin for an LCD that is being delivered.  This is personal opinion, but I would never buy an LCD in a retail store.

Answer (score 1):

[Dead Pixel Tester](http://www.dataproductservices.com/dpt) is also good for checking such things.

[image: DPT main screen]

It allows you to fill your screen with different colors or patterns, in order to see if there are dead pixels on it.